# Create React App - Unable to set window object before test runs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, jsdom

Trying to set up some tests for a component in a CRA-generated application.

Having an issue where the test is failing to run due to an imported file relying on a window object which isn't initialised.

Quick overview:
In `public/index.html` there is an object defined on the window called `window.config`.

```html
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/config.js"></script>
<script>
  // THESE PROPERTIES ARE DEFINED IN config.js
  window.config = {
    ENV,
    IDENTITY_URL,
    OIDC_CLIENT_ID,
  };
</script>
```

There is a file called `identity.constants.js` which exports an object that uses these window variables.

```js
export const IdentityConfig = {
    authority: window.config.IDENTITY_URL,
    client_id: window.config.OIDC_CLIENT_ID,
    ... etc
};
```

The component I am trying to test imports another component that relies on `identity.constants.js` shown above.

The problem is that the test fails to start and throws an error stating `window.config` is `undefined` from the `identity.constants.js` file.

After reading the CRA docs, I have tried adding the following code into `src/setupTests.js` to set the config object before the test starts but it seems to fail before this code runs.

```js
global.config = {
  ENV: "development",
  IDENTITY_URL: "identityurl.com",
  OIDC_CLIENT_ID: "i-am-a-clientId",
  ... etc
};
```

I'm looking for a way to set this window variable before the tests run (or a better way to structure the way I'm using window variables) so I can successfully run my tests.

Comment: What version of react were you using for this scenario? I have the same issue but the below solution does not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`globa.config` defines a global variable named `config`, you'll need to define `global.window` firstly, then add `config` as a property of `global.window`.
It seems your test environment is `node`, if you have `jsdom` as the `devDependencies` of your project, try to add below piece of code to your `setupTests.js`:

```js
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

const jsdom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.window = jsdom.window;
global.document = jsdom.window.document;

global.window.config = {
  ENV: "development",
  IDENTITY_URL: "identityurl.com",
  OIDC_CLIENT_ID: "i-am-a-clientId",
  ... etc
};
```

Without `jsdom`, a simple fix is like below:

```js
global.window = {
  config: {
    ENV: "development",
    IDENTITY_URL: "identityurl.com",
    OIDC_CLIENT_ID: "i-am-a-clientId",
    ... etc
  }
}
```

Comment: The "without jsdom" way didn't work, but importing it did. Thanks!